# No logging happens for jdbc in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

In my application.properties I have

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```

and the below dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But no logging happens for jdbc statements, although my main application's INFO level logs are appearing. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure log levels in Spring Boot, you should use properties with the form `logging.level.<logger-name>=<level>`. For your two loggers, the properties should be:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```

You can learn more in the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.log-levels) of the Spring Boot reference documentation.

Comment: That worked. Why don't the log4j settings I tried work, as this is suggested in some other places?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what those other places are. Spring Boot itself does not support the properties that you were trying to use. Perhaps what you saw in other places was relying on an additional dependencies to map the entries in `application.properties` to Log4j 2 configuration?

Comment: Ok, thanks for hte info.